# What is the best way to make a JOIN query while using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently doing it like this.

Is there a better way?

```
public Cursor selectRostersForTeam(Activity activity, int teamId) {

    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT r." + _ROSTER_ID + ", t." + _TEAM_ID + ", t." + TEAM_NAME + ", t." + TEAM_SEASON_WINS + ", t." + TEAM_SEASON_LOSSES + ", t." + TEAM_CHAMPIONSHIP_WINS + ", j." + _TEAMS_ROSTERS_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_TEAM + " AS p" + " JOIN " + TABLE_TEAMS_ROSTERS + " j ON (r." + _ROSTER_ID + " = j." + TEAMS_ROSTER_ROSTER_ID + ") " + " JOIN " + TABLE_TEAM + " ch ON (j." + TEAMS_ROSTER_TEAM_ID + " = t." + _TEAM_ID + ") WHERE j. " + TEAMS_ROSTER_TEAM_ID + " = " + teamId + ";";



    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);

    activity.startManagingCursor(cursor);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to `rawQuery()` would be `query()`, but that one is not designed for joins.

If you think your join is important enough, you could [create a view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) out of it and then use it at the table for `query()`.

---

Note: it is recommended to pass values like `teamId` as parameters instead of formatting them into the query string:

```
rawQuery(..._TEAM_ID + " = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(teamId) });
```